# Destroying RNA of viruses using Ribonuclease

Tags: immunology, rna, retrovirus

I wonder if it is possible to design some Ribonuclease to destroy only specific RNAs (like those of viruses). Then, if virus tries to infect, his RNA will be cut.

Or, instead of creating Ribonuclease, we can design suitable mRNA and let the cell do the rest.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, this site is for questions and answers not discussions. We also expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). See also this sites criteria for ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework), which can apply to questions even if they are not assigned as homework. Thanks! 

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Answer (score 1):

The human body basically [does this on its own](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=Mammalian%20antimicrobial%20proteins%20and%20peptides%3A%20overview%20on%20the%20RNase%20A%20superfamily%20members%20involved%20in%20innate%20host%20defence&publication_year=2007&author=E.%20Boix&author=M.V.%20Nogues). We express various RNAses, some of which appear to have [specific antiviral or bactericidal roles](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2692241/).

(This appears to be due to both RNAse activity and to biochemical properties of the proteins independent of RNA digestion)

Comment: How about creating some drug based on this technique? Could this help fight the infection?

Comment: @Dzery I would say rather that it _does_ help fight infections, as part of normal human biology. And sure, you could package these RNAses up into pills or in an aerosol spray or something. I don't know of any specific examples though.

Comment: that's the point - maybe it's a way to create a new type of drug?

Answer (score 0):

CRISPR/cas is used for exactly this purpose in bacteria.
The CRISPR array contains sequences from bacteriophages, which will prime various cas-nucleases to cleave either the DNA or the RNA of the virus.